# shell script waiting for process to finish which run in new terminal

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, osx-yosemite

I am trying to write shell script file for compiling refactorerl this is my code :

`#!/bin/sh
osascript -e 'tell application "terminal"' -e 'do script "cd /Users/MacBookAir/Desktop/refactorerl-0.9.14.09 && sudo bin/referl -build tool && exit "'   -e 'end tell'`
    code is runing ,but my problem is that I want terminal to wait till the build proccess is finishing then continue in this code Terminal is not waiting for the process to complite...I am using os x Yosetime 10.10.5 .....any idea...!?? tnx

Comment: This Q is more appropriate to the related site http://apple.stackexchange.com (AskDifferently). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Actually it's Ask Different, not Differently ;-)

Comment: @4ae1e1 : Thanks, I don't have a OSX machine, so was just winging it. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of letting osascript parse your && logic, maybe you can change it bit like that:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "terminal"' -e 'do script "cd /Users/MacBookAir/Desktop/refactorerl-0.9.14.09"' -e 'end tell' && sudo bin/referl -build tool
```

If script

```
cd /Users/MacBookAir/Desktop/refactorerl-0.9.14.09
```

succeeds, run

```
sudo bin/referl -build tool
```